# How to send data on event fire over websocket to client

Tags: events, asp.net-core, websocket

Couple of days ago I ran into some kind of a problem that I can't seem to solve. So that's why I'm posting it on StackOverflow.

I'm running a .NET CORE website that can run a task in the background. Such a task has 3 events (OnCompleted, OnStarted, TaskProgress). What I need is that if any of these events fire, he will send data to the connected clients. For simplicity, I want to return the "event fired" string.

What I have done for the moment is the following:

- added `app.UseWebSockets()` to my startup.cs file
- added a new function to the pipeline to catch the websocket calls

  ```
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
      if (context.Request.Path == "/socket")
      {
          if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
          {
              var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
              //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
          }
          else
          {
              context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          await next();
      }
  });
  ```
- I created a `SocketListener` class that receives all 3 events when fired.

  ```
  private void _taskManager_TaskExecuting(object sender, GenericEventArgs<IScheduledTaskWorker> e)
  {
      SendData();
  }

  private void _taskManager_TaskCompleted(object sender, TaskCompletionEventArgs e)
  {
      SendData();
  }

  private void Argument_TaskProgress(object sender, GenericEventArgs<double> e)
  {
      SendData();
  }
  ```

So what I would need now is that in the pipeline function (//HERE IS MY PROBLEM line) I somehow wait for unlimited time for any of the events to fire. If they fire, the `SocketListener` class needs to be aware of the connections and send data back over the WebSocket connection.

The `SendData()' function will need to check for open connections and send the "event fired" string to all of them.

The connection also needs to be closed when navigating away from the page. I think I can manage that with some angular NavigationStart event and then call the socket api with a close message.

I searched on the internet for a good solution but most of the blogpost/tutorials/... are talking about 2-way communication (chat programs,...)

Anyone got an idea how I could fix this problem? If more information is needed I let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Helo Reggi,

I've open sourced an WebSocket application that I built in .NET Core.

I've built it to process generic messages, not only focused on chats.

My idea is use two way communication within the client (WebPage) and the websocket to perform any kind of task.

WebSocket communication works slightly different from what you say on you question, but the code I've written is going to be a good guide.

What you want to do with SendData is going to be like the method 'NotifyAllConnectedSockets' on the controller NotificationController that I've created.

Please take a look to see if it suits to what you want.

BackEnd - https://github.com/asiilva/WSMessageHandler

Front-end - https://github.com/asiilva/ws-message-handler-front

Note: It is a work in progres, either front and back-end.

Feel free to ask any question

Best Regards

Comment: Your idea of the WebSocketConnectionManager is a very good idea! I will have a try with your code in mind!

Comment: Í just want to remind you of up voting my answer if you think it fits. Thank you and feel free to ask any qurstion.

Comment: It would be great to post the answer here (just the concept at least), if you know the solution

Comment: @MehdiDehghani have you taken a look at the GtiHub repo? Don't you think the answer I've given is not enough? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlanSilva actually I solved the problem using another approach, and yes, I checked the repo, it's great to share the full source code, but I think sharing the main section _related to the question_ is nice, so the reader can decide to continue to the full source code or not (full source code is related to the problem or not), good luck